# Why is there no narrowing conversion in this code, resulting in an error?

Tags: c++, c++11

`g++` with `-std=c++11` seems to accept it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

std::vector<float> vf={1,2,3}; // Isn't this narrowing (i.e., an error)?

int main() {}
```

It would seem that the line with the comment should error out, but it does not.

**Update**

Thanks to Jesse for pointing to the standardese (8.5.4 p7) that defines why this is OK. Here is some sample code that helps to clarify the behavior defined by the standard:

```
const int v5=5;
int v6=6;

vector<double> vd1={1,2,3,4};       // OK
vector<double> vd2={1,2,3,4,v5};    // Still OK, v5 is const
vector<double> vd3={1,2,3,4,v5,v6}; // Error, narrowing conversion, because v6 
                                    // is non-const
vector<double> vd4={1,2,3,4,v5,static_cast<const int>(v6)}; // Also errors on 
                                    // gcc 4.7.2, not sure why.
```

I hope that the examples I just presented will help others to get past some narrowing issues when using initializer lists.

If anyone knows why the last case violates the standard definition, please post a comment.

Comment: Why do you think it’s narrowing?

Comment: Narrowing would be from `float` to `int`

Comment: How is that conversion narrowing? GCC does [issue a warning](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1FWK1L$2) when narrowing is detected, and you can turn that into an error by [compiling with `-pedantic-errors`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1FWK1L$1).

Comment: @Andy & Praetorian, not necessarily, see the update.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Both int->float *and* float->int are at least potentially narrowing. In a typical case, both are 32-bits total, with the float having greater range, but the int more precision, so converting in either direction can lose information.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Yes, I realized that, but thank you for pointing out

Comment: Re: "Weird, I know, but that's the standard for you." No, that's your lack of understanding for you.

Comment: @Pete, that was very constructive of you...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rules are in 8.5.4 p7 which excludes your example

> from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to a floating-point
>   type, *except where the source is a constant expression and the actual
>   value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce
>   the original value when converted back to the original type*, or …

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: Good find and thanks for the reference. I wasn't aware that constant expressions were treated differently.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: Because of what it said. `v5` is a constant expression, but `v6` *is not*. Nor can you magically convert something that isn't a constant expression into something that is.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: As Nicol Bolas points out, it is the same reason why you cannot do `int array[static_cast<const int>(v6)];`, the cast does not make it a constant expression.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see why this should error out given that all three integers can be exactly represented as `float`.

That said, I can get `g++` to give me a warning if I include a constant that doesn't fit in a `float`:

```
warning: narrowing conversion of '2112112112' from 'int' to 'float' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```